# Как на сайте распределить элементы поровну на одной странице с перелистыванием?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-core

Хочу реализовать то что вы видите на картинке. Есть например много новостей и нужно чтобы они все были на одной странице но автоматически распределены на несколько страниц.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ОТВЕТ НАЙДЕН
Это называется "Пагинация". Если вдруг кому поможет то как ее реализовать хорошо разъясняется здесь:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndNWcZko64s

Comment: Это называется пагинация. Реализация зависит от СУБД и ORM.